# Creating a select box dynamically with data from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, for-loop

i am trying to create a select box dynamically with data that is within an array, I tried watching some JSON tutorials, yet having some trouble still.

```
 var clothes = [
     Red Dress:"reddress.png",
     Blue Dress:"bluedress.png",
     Black Hair Pin:"hairpin.png"
 ];

 var select = '<select id="clothing_options">';
 for(var i=0;i<clothes.length;i++)
 {
     select +='<option value="'+secondPart[i]+'">'+firstPart[i]+'</option>';
 }

 $('#select_box_wrapper').append(select+'</select>');

 $('#clothing_options').change(function() {
     var image_src = $(this).val();
     $('#clothing_image').attr('src','http://www.imagehosting.com/'+image_src);
 });
```

as you can see code is not fully functioning because it is not written correctly. How do I get the data for value from the second part and the option text from the first part? basically html should look like this

```
   <select id="clothing_options">
      <option value="reddress.png">Red Dress</option>
      <option value="bluedress.png">Blue Dress</option>
      <option value="hairpin.png">Black Hair Pin</option>
   </select>
```

thanks for any explanations or suggestions. Just want this code to work, as I am just doing these codes for lessons for myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your array to a JSON object..

```
var clothes = {
 "Red Dress":"reddress.png",
 "Blue Dress":"bluedress.png",
 "Black Hair Pin":"hairpin.png"
};
```

and then iteration becomes easier..

```
for(var item in clothes)
{
  $('<option value="'+item+'">'+clothes[item]+'</option>').appendTo('#clothing_options');
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="select_box_wrapper">
  <select id="clothing_options"></select>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/60823)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now for the line of for(var item in clothes) can item be anything?

Comment: yes, the var 'item' could be called anything. It represents each item in the json object.

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

```
var clothes = {
 Red_Dress:"reddress.png",
 Blue_Dress:"bluedress.png",
 Black_Hair_Pin:"hairpin.png"
};
```

You can't have spaces in identifiers.

Second, to loop through an object:

```
 for (var key in clothes)
 {
     select +='<option value="'+clothes[key]+'">'+key+'</option>';
 }
```

Of course this has the undesired effect of showing 'Red_Dress' in the select box.

```
var clothes = {
 "Red Dress":"reddress.png",
 "Blue Dress":"bluedress.png",
 "Black Hair Pin":"hairpin.png"
};
```

That will fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of all of this